# how to use ng-controller after version 1.2.29?

Tags: angularjs

I was following an AngularJs tutorial based on version 1.2 and I saw it doesn't work on the latest 1.7.2 version.
After few tests, I realized it doesn't work on version 1.3+ but according to the doc, I really don't see any difference on `ng-controller` using.

My code is:

```
    <div id="example" ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="comment in comments | filter:{content: query} | orderBy: order">
            <p>
                <strong>{{comment.username}}</strong><br/>
                {{comment.content}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

   <script>
        function CommentsCtrl($scope) {

            $scope.comments=[
                {
                    "username": "Geraldine",
                    "city": "Dola",
                    "email": "geraldinemaddox@enervate.com",
                    "content": "Dolor consectetur..."
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    </script>
```

To allow you to better look at the problem, the code is here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lor2h3ks/1/)

What's wrong please?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong that need to be updated if you are updating to 1.7.2.

First you need to register your module like so

```
angular.module("app", [])
```

On your body tag change it to

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

Then you need to register the controller to the angular module

```
angular.module("app").controller('CommentsCtrl', function CommentsCtrl($scope) {
  // Controller code here
});
```

I put all the changes into a fork of your fiddle [jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/gbj09xov/1)